# Squid proxy can't access a Cloudflare protected website

Tags: proxy, cloudflare, squid, centos8

I have set up squid proxy on my CentOS8 and it's working just fine on all websites except on one website that has Cloudflare protection.

I get this error

```
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.
```

Below is my config file (I didn't include everything, just things that i think are important)

Is there a way to further configure it correctly ?

````
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Basic Authentication
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl auth_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow auth_users
forwarded_for off
request_header_access Allow allow all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authenticate allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Expires allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Last-Modified allow all
request_header_access Location allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Content-Language allow all
request_header_access Mime-Version allow all
request_header_access Retry-After allow all
request_header_access Title allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection allow all
request_header_access User-Agent allow all
request_header_access Cookie allow all
request_header_access All deny all ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the website has blocked the IP address of your squid proxy server, which is very common if your are running squid proxy on hosting server.

Somebody may have used the IP address of a nearby IP address for suspicious activity.

Or maybe that website didn't want any vps to allow access.

Since almost all normal users are using their own device, not hosting servers.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, so i'm assuming there is no way to bypass this ?

Comment: If your are running squid proxy on hosting server, you can bypass it by running it on non-hosting server.

Comment: I have the same problem, if I disable squid ( use other browser ) there is no problem. It's something to do with certificates I guess